# Difference between a const inside a proc vs outside

Tags: constants, nim-lang

This is probably a really dumb question, but other than visibility is there any real difference between a `const` inside a `proc` vs outside?

```
const foo = "FOO"

proc test() =
  const bar = "BAR"
  echo foo & bar

test()
```

Like when inside, does the stack grow and shrink for that `const` every time the `proc` is invoked, or because it's a `const` is it just held in a static memory location for the duration of the application?

I'm asking specifically about Nim but reflections on differences/similarities in other languages are welcome too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the generated C code, you will see this line:

```
STRING_LITERAL(TMP139, "FOOBAR", 6);
```

What this tells us is `foo & bar` was evaluated at compile time.

`nimbase.h` has this:

```
#define STRING_LITERAL(name, str, length) \
  static const struct {                   \
    TGenericSeq Sup;                      \
    NIM_CHAR data[(length) + 1];          \
  } name = {{length, length}, str}
```

`const` in Nim is much more than a static memory location. But it does seem like in this case we get the string `"FOOBAR"` in a static memory location. However, if we replace these strings with numbers, for example, `1` and `3`, the generated code just has a `4` literal without any storage.

Now, for the actual question. The only difference here is the scope in which the constants are seen.

If this wasn't simplified in such a way (e.g. if you wrote `echo foo\\echo bar`), we can consult the generated code again and see two identical (except for content) `STRING_LITERAL` declarations.

Comment: Thanks. I can see how most of the code would be optimized away in my simple example but your last sentence seems to answer what I'm after.